# normalizing django models

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

i try to make an app for a mobile store

```
class Mobile(models.Model):
    model= models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    edited_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Storage(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(Mobile,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='models')
    IMEI = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    buying_price = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    cost_price = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    odd_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    mul_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    second_hand = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    edited_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.IMEI
```

should i change it to create a new table(model) from `Storage` named `Prices` to normalizing and performance or its fine ?thanks